# Is there any Finite State Machine defination for SQL?

Tags: sql, standards, grammar, fsm, automata

Does anyone know if there is any Finite State Machine definition for SQL such as PL/SQL,SQL92 or SQL99..

Don't know if there is any grammar definition of SQL..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ANTLR has SQL and PL/SQL grammars:

http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list

Comment: Thanks!Actually I am going to write my own ANTLR SQL parser, so I am looking for standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you may be looking for, but it can help

the SQL as understood by SQLite

https://sqlite.org/lang.html